# Check users data to access a Collection

Tags: meteor

I want to check a specific field in the users collection to give permissions to modify another collection. This is my code:

```js
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Empleados = new Mongo.Collection('empleados');

Empleados.allow({
  insert(userId, empleado) {
    return userId;
  },

  update(userId, empleado, fields, modifier) {
    return userId;
  },

  remove(userId, empleado) {
    return userId
  }
});
```

I can check the userId, but how do I check the other fields of the users collection? I am using the accounts-password package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your "allow" rules:

`insert: (userId, doc) ->
      if (doc.user_id == userId && Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId}).isAdmin)
        true
      else
        false`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need to verify, but right now I'm struggling with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798049/access-to-a-collection-from-resolve 
Maybe you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the alanning:roles package to your project, which will allow you to give roles to users and you can check if they have the right role assigned to do the operation.

Alternatively you could add a flag to the Meteor.user().profile object in the user record, and look at that to decide.