# Access to a collection from resolve

Tags: angularjs, meteor

How can I verify a specific field from the users collection of the accounts module of meteor ?

Supposing the next code:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
  resolve:{
    function($q) {
      if(Meteor.userId()){
        return $q.resolve();
      }

      else {
        retrun $q.reject();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Inside the resolve is possible to use the Meteor.userId() function to retrieve the _id from the user, but I cant use the Meteor.user() function in the same way. How can I retrieve custom data from that collection from the resolve

Comment: Why can't you use `Meteor.user()` in the same way? Doesn't this function return the whole `user` object?

Comment: Yes, it should, or at least I guess it should but... It doesn't, maybe has something to be with the execution order in which Angular loads the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little tricky, but solvable with this code in your state:

```
resolve: {
    currentUser: ($q) => {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Meteor.autorun(function () {
            if (!Meteor.loggingIn()) {
                if (Meteor.user() == null) {
                    deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
                } else {
                    deferred.resolve(Meteor.user());
                }
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the route does not resolve until the Meteor.user() record is loaded, and if not logged in, rejects the route. It took me a while to find this one, but it's a keeper now :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to implement it to my code, but it doesn't resolve the view, can you check this gist and see if I'm doing something wrong ? 

https://gist.github.com/2JN/31bbe6589c450b1df5eadc025d4da06e

Comment: Instead of usuario() you should have usuario:

Comment: Thank you Mikkel you are awesome! I was doing something wrong, but you where right this solve my problem, where can I read more about this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the gist, the below code is how my helpers look

```
this.helpers({
    member: () => Members.findOne({mid: Meteor.userId()}),
    currentUser: () => {
        return Meteor.user();
    },
```

Comment: Is it possible to access a helper outside the class ?

Comment: Also, I realize what I was doing wrong, It seems that the function inside the resolve must be an arrow function :(